# How i can fix this error in jboss: Failed to recover cluster state after the current node became the coordinator

Tags: java, server, jboss

I have deployed my system in jboss server, specifically in 3 nodes, usually everyday in the morning in the logs i get the next errors:

1- 2020-04-02 03:34:07,810 ERROR [org.infinispan.topology.ClusterTopologyManagerImpl] (transport-thread-2) ISPN000196: Failed to recover cluster state after the current node became the coordinator: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException.

2- 2020-04-02 04:03:53,818 ERROR [org.jboss.as.clustering] (Incoming-1,shared=udp) JBAS010223: ViewAccepted failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS010240: Address e10e5b3d-98c8-86bc-fa53-16ec8e2d2a43 not registered in the transport layer.

3- [org.jboss.as.clustering] (VERIFY_SUSPECT.TimerThread,web,host1:system/web) JBAS010232: Suspect member: e10e5b3d-98c8-86bc-fa53-16ec8e2d2a43

**Notes:**

1. Due to the configuration of my system, it's deploy every morning when it detects changes in the 
   production code.
2. Jboss Version:jboss-eap-6.4.19

**Anyone knows what mean this errors and what i've to do to fix them?**

**After that, my application stops, i can't sign in and i have to restart all my nodes to make it work again :|**

Thank you very much for in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, looking at the messages you have, it seems to be unable to share instances of each applications between your jboss server 6.4.9 nodes.

Maybe you will find usefull these link with the detailed configuration I have put below :

```
     <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">  
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>  
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>  
        <socket-binding name="hotrod" port="11222"/>  
        <socket-binding name="hotrod-internal" port="11223"/>  
        <socket-binding name="hotrod-multi-tenancy" port="11224"/>  
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:234.99.54.14}" multicast-port="45700"/>  
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" port="7600"/>  
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" port="57600"/>  
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:234.99.54.14}" multicast-port="45688"/>  
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" port="54200"/>  
        <socket-binding name="memcached" port="11211"/>  
        <socket-binding name="rest" port="8080"/>  
        <socket-binding name="rest-multi-tenancy" port="8081"/>  
        <socket-binding name="rest-ssl" port="8443"/>  
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>  
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>  
        <socket-binding name="websocket" port="8181"/>  
        <outbound-socket-binding name="remote-store-hotrod-server">  
            <remote-destination host="remote-host" port="11222"/>  
        </outbound-socket-binding>  
        <outbound-socket-binding name="remote-store-rest-server">  
            <remote-destination host="remote-host" port="8080"/>  
        </outbound-socket-binding>  
    </socket-binding-group>
```

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/277313

[Javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/6.0/apidocs/overview-summary.html)